# Declaring a "global" object in objective C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I'm creating a social media app, so it follows the basic structure of an app like Twitter. I have a user class that contains a bunch of methods, like `loadFeed` and `postContent`. The user class has a few properties, one of which is userID. So basically a user object is created, and the app displays content relevant to that user.

Currently I've only tested by creating the same object in every implementation file. However, I want to create one global object that all the classes can use. How can I do this?

Comment: So would you recommend me adding a singleton method to my `user` class to share the instance variable? @trojanfoe

Comment: Yes.  There are many examples of how to do it.

Comment: check mark, if agree...

Answer (score 2):

You have few option depends on your requirements.

#### 1. Declare a `global` variable in a `header` class.

In your project, press `command+N` > `C and C++` > `Header File`. Declare a `object` there. `Import` this header file in every class you want to use that `global` object, and use it.

#### 2. Save value in `NSUserDefault`

Next you can save a variable in a `NSUserDefault`. It works as same as `Session` works in web apps, provided, it does not expire automatically.

#### 3. Singleton pattern.

For `singleton` pattern, you need to have little lengthy processes but this is most `memory efficient` and best technique. Go through **[Singletons in Objective-C](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)** article